# deploy symfony 4.2 project to shared hosting by filezilla

Tags: symfony, cpanel, symfony4, shared-hosting

i have a project that build on with Symfony 4.2. I want deploy this project to a shared hosting. But on symfony documentation, there is nothing about it clearly.

I deployed all my project into hosting under public_html.

But probably panel does not find the index.php. On cpanel, i can not change the document root.

current document root: `public_html`

[project folder structure](https://i.hizliresim.com/r5Z9dM.png)

my index.php under public folder.

```
   <?php

   use App\Kernel;
   use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

   require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

   if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
        umask(0000);

        Debug::enable();
   }

   if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? 
        $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
        Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), 
  Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
   }

   if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? 
       $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
            Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
   }

   $kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) 
   $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
   $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
   $response = $kernel->handle($request);
   $response->send();
   $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Can someone help me about this issue?

Comment: You will waste a lot of time deploying on a shared hosting. Symfony is not meant for that even it is possible. There are very cheap virtual private servers where you will full control of deployment. (and to stick with good practices)

Comment: @COil Yes, i know that but my customer wants this way.

Comment: have you tried to change .htaccess file in the root of project ?

Comment: @hous I did not. I just upload all my files under public_html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a symfony4 application running under shared hosting ,so try this configuration in the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

for assets try this in framework.yaml

```
    assets:
        base_path: '/public'
```

Comment: Thanks, it seem works. But project does not find my css, js, images files for now.

Comment: base_path does not work, just uploading all files again maybe it works.

Comment: This is the correct way, but I would try to point your host to the public directory, as it is safer. I will add another answer with slight changes.

Answer (score 0):

People saying that symfony is not meant for this are just utterly wrong!

Symfony does not state anything about how to host it, it is (almost) completely agnostic about it's hosting platform. The only thing you need to do is forward your server requests to the public/index.php.

I am hosting at OVH cloud, which is semi-private hosting. I got it working by pointing my domain names in the control panel to www/mysymfonyapp/public and add a .htaccess to the public directory:

```
# mysymfonyapp/public/.htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Works like a charm!